# Equality of two free modules of the same finite rank under strong hypothesis.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, free-modules, formal-power-series

So basically the question is the one of the title of the post, but let me show you the context:

Let $\mathbb K$ be an algebraic closed field and let $f\in \mathbb K[X,Y]$ be a polynomial such that is monic over $Y$ and $(0,0)\in V_{\mathbb K}(f)$. You can also use that $V_{\mathbb K}(X)$ does not belong to the tangent cone of $V_{\mathbb K}(f)$ in $(0,0)$.

I already know that $f$ factorises in $\mathbb K\{\{X\}\}[Y]$ where $\mathbb K\{\{X\}\}$ is the Puiseux's series ring. As a consequence:
$$
f=\prod_i(Y-q_i)
$$
where $q_i\in\mathbb K\{\{X\}\}$. If we put toghether the conjugate roots we can write
$$
f=f_1\cdot...\cdot f_t
$$
where $f_i=\prod_{j=1}^{r_i}(Y-q_{ij})\in\mathbb K[[X]]$ and $q_{ij}\in\mathbb K[[X^{1/r_i}]]$ are the conjugate roots. Notice that $\mathbb K[[X]]$ is the formal power series ring. Here is the diagram with everything I know so far:
$$
\begin{array}[c]
 a&  & \mathbb K[[X^{1/r_i}]] &\cong &\mathbb K[[X]]^{r_i} \\
  & & \qquad\cup \\
\frac{\mathbb K[[X]][Y]}{\left<f_i\right>}&\cong & \mathbb K[[X]][q_i]&\cong &\mathbb K[[X]]^{r_i} \\
 &  & \qquad\cup \\
 &  & \;\;\;\mathbb K[[X]]
\end{array}
$$

In the diagram $q_i$ is one of the roots $q_{ij}$. My question is:

**Can we prove that $\mathbb K[[X^{1/r_i}]]=\mathbb K[[X]][q_i]$ under all the given assumptions?**

Let me know if you need more information or if something I wrote is wrong. Thanks in advance!